# Creating a Random Date from a range of years?

Tags: apex

I would like to know if we can achieve a random date value through Apex when given with the upper and lower limits. Referred this documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/07/selecting-random-numbers-and-records-on-the-force-com-platform-part-1.html but it's more of generating a random number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should get you where you want to go (mostly):

```
public static Date randomDate(Date min, Date max) {
    // Convert to DateTime values
    DateTime mint = min, maxt = max.addDays(1);
    // Then convert to milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970, and get difference in ms
    Long minms = mint.getTime(), maxms = maxt.getTime(), diff = maxms - minms;
    // Return a date between minms and maxms.
    return DateTime.newInstance(
        minms + Math.mod(Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomLong()), diff)
    ).date();
}
```

You'll want to look at the Crypto, Math, Date, and DateTime classes for more information.

---

To actually get dates in given years:

```
public static Date randomDateFromYears(Integer startYear, Integer endYear) {
  return randomDate(Date.newInstance(startYear, 1, 1), Date.newInstance(endYear, 12, 31));
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you do this using milliseconds rather than just getting a random number of days to add to the minimum date?

Comment: @Dupe_jockey Sorry, ignore my previous comment about randomness. Really, both do about the same thing (except you still need to remember to add a day if you want maxDate to be included as a possible result), this was just the first method that came to mind.

Comment: I've tried this code running on an anonymous window: `DataCreationCtrl ctrl = new DataCreationCtrl();
System.debug('temp: ' +ctrl.randomDate(1995, 1999));` Error: `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void randomDate(Integer, Integer) from the type DataCreationCtrl`. And I have removed Static variable from the method.

Comment: @AustinEvans (a) using static methods would be more effective, you don't need to construct this class, and (b) added an example of a method for actually getting a date from the years you specify as Integer values.

Comment: Hey @sfdcfox I just ran a Batch job and I am not sure why I got 2k+ records out of 10k got created with date more than 2 years. My inputs were: (1995,1999), still I get to see 2000 and 2001 years. Weird!!!

Answer (score 7):

One way to approach this could be to use `Date.daysBetween()` to get the number of days in your range, then use `Math.random()` multiplied by that number to get a random number of days into your range. Then `Date.addDays()` to add your resulting number of days to the minimum date for your final result.

Scratch code (untested):

```
public Date randomDate(Date minDate, Date maxDate)
{
    Integer rangeSize = minDate.daysBetween(maxDate) + 1;
    Decimal daysToAdd = rangeSize * math.Random();
    Date result = minDate.addDays(daysToAdd.intValue());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: If I don't mind asking, can you please share sample code snippet?

Comment: Just added some scratch code, not totally sure about data type compatibility btw Integers and Decimals with these methods though.

Comment: This code will almost never return the maxDate (because of decimal multiplication rounding down when converted to an integer). You'll need to add a day to get the last date to appear. Also, it would be `daysToAdd.intValue()` to get back to an Integer that `addDays` expects.

Comment: Good calls, I've fixed my snippet accordingly

Comment: @Dupe_jockey You actually need to +1 the rangeSize (by adding a day to maxDate or by +1 on daysBetween). The new edit can't return the minDate.